# Compare 2 files in awk and append Pass / Fail

Tags: awk, comparison

Thank you all for the feedback.  Apologies since I am newer to coding and new to SO.  Below is the code I have currently been running.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4,$5]=$0}{if(b=a[$4,$5]); print b, "PASS";next}else{if(b!=a[$4,$5]){print a, b, "FAIL";next}}'
```

This appends a PASS next to each line if it is the same, but does print FAIL if there are any inconsistencies in the line.

Trying to get myself more familiar with awk.  Using FNR==NR I've been able to compare 2 files (line by line) and then print PASS at the end of the file.  However, I cannot actually get it to properly fail the scenario and print FAIL if they do not match.  Could anybody help a noobie out?

Comment: As a general rule in SO - when you ask such question it is good to post some code. Edit the question so someone can try to help you. Yuor question is too broad and can be closed.

Comment: Also **edit your question** to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output. Us the `{}` editor button to format that and your code attempt properly. The best way to get familiar with awk is to start by reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Sounds like your pass logic is actually broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some `awk` script to get you started.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} 
              {f=$0!=a[FNR]; delete a[FNR]} 
             f{c=FNR;exit} 
           END{c=c?c:(FNR+1);print f||(c in a)?"FAIL on line "c:"PASS"}'
```

additional complexity is due to files might have different lengths.  Note also that there are existing tools (diff, comm, ...) to do this in a much compact way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This is a little different than I am looking for, did edit my question to show you what I have going.

Comment: Do you know what `if(b=a[$4,$5]);` means in your code?  It's just assigning a value to `b`.  If you indent your code (like mine) and pay attention to `;` and assignment vs equality check I guess you can discover the issues on your own.

Comment: Not looking to indent, looking to do it on one line

Comment: @AndyBlair There is no cost having more than one line, formatting is a tool to help you to deal with complexity.  Once you have a solution it's easier to compress it.